# Javascript and HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to make a drawing I made in the canvas change shape dynamically based on variables I pass in. what I have is that if want to change the shape of the monster or make it bigger, I have to change a lot of values to make it happen, how do I make all my number so that when I change it at 1 place, the change happens everywhere.
[Here is the code on codepen](https://codepen.io/alphaQue/pen/qjOOYZ)

Javascript code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var width = 0;
var height = 0;
var radius = 0;

var squareLength = 450;

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = '#33b262';
//Translate to the center of the canvas
ctx.translate(x+ 450, y+ 350);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI /4);
ctx.translate(x+ (-(squareLength / 2)), y+ (- (squareLength / 2)));
ctx.fillRect(x + 0,y+ 0,  width + squareLength, height+ 
squareLength);
ctx.restore();
ctx.closePath();

// eye
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x + 450, y+ 210, radius+ 75, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

// eye black filling
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x + 450, y+ 210, radius+ 17, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

//mouth
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.restore();
ctx.translate(x+ 250,y+ 100);
ctx.rect(x + 100,y+ 300, width + 200,height+ 70);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

//left tooth
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.restore();
ctx.rect(x + 135,y+ 300, width + 30,height+ 30);
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

//right tooth
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.restore();
ctx.rect(x + 237,y+ 300, width + 30,height+ 30);
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

//bottom tooth
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.restore();
ctx.rect(x + 185,y+ 340, width + 30,height+ 30);
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

//left leg
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = '#800000';
ctx.moveTo(x + 303, y+ 465);
ctx.lineTo(x + 335, y+ 433);
ctx.lineTo(x + 335, y+ 615);
ctx.lineTo(x + 303, y+ 615);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

//right leg
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = '#800000';
ctx.moveTo(x + 97, y+ 465);
ctx.lineTo(x + 65, y+ 433);
ctx.lineTo(x + 65, y+ 615);
ctx.lineTo(x + 97, y+ 615);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

//right shoe
ctx.fillStyle = '#330000';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x + 319, y+ 660, radius+ 65, 0, 1 * Math.PI, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

//right shoe
ctx.fillStyle = '#330000';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x + 79, y+ 660, radius+ 65, 0, 1 * Math.PI, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: Wow. Just wow. Canvas is really more suited to animated sprites. Not saying you can't do this, but... anyway answer to your question is to bind numbers to names with `var` declarations like you already have for `width` and `height`

Comment: i want the drawing to be parametric based on variables x, y ,width, and height, so later on i can change the shape of the drawing or move it based on changing just 4 numbers

Comment: You write an object - "monster". You then put a bunch of params to it, one of it being scale. Then you redraw monster and put in a different scale. There is no magical way to do it. You need a function to adjust your numbers manually based on your scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for the drawing you are creating like VSO suggested like this..

```
class Drawing {
    constructor(x, y, scale) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    get size() {
        return [Number(this.x) * Number(this.scale), Number(this.y) * Number(this.scale)];
    }

}
var draw = new Drawing(10, 15, 5);
document.write('(Scaled) X:' + draw.size[0] + ' Y:' + draw.size[1]);
```